# How to access Google Maps markers after creating them dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am creating markers for multiple points like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

  console.log("Adding marker...");

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map,
            draggable:true,
            icon: locations[i][3]
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(){

      console.log(marker.getPosition());
      // This doesn't work :(
  });

}
```

I then want to (with `getPosition`) access the positions (lat & long) of each marker when they are moved. How would I achieve that? There will most likely always be 2 markers on the map, so I would need to access marker `0` and marker `1` and log each of them when they are moved.

UPDATE 1:

I tried adding `id: locations[i][0]` to the marker and then accessing it with: `console.log(marker.id);` But that always returns the ID/name of the second marker, even if the first one is moved.

Comment: You will have t push every marker in a globally define array and then access the array
var gmMarkers = [];
gmMarkers.push(marker);
then you can access it using
for (var i = 0; i < gmMarkers.length; i++) {
                gmMarkers[i].setIcon(iconUrl)
        }

Comment: add an event listener for each marker individual marker

Answer (score 3):

Use `this` inside the click listener to reference the marker thing that was clicked.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(){
  console.log(this.getPosition());
});
```

Comment: That's more sensible way to do it. No need to maintain array
+1 for this keyword :)

Answer (score 0):

You store the markers into an array while creating them

```js
var arr_marker=[];
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

  console.log("Adding marker...");

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map,
            draggable:true,
            icon: locations[i][3]
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(){

      console.log(marker.getPosition());
      // This doesn't work :(
  });
arr_marker[] = marker;
}
```